# Slow input for Pixel and Tonic's Matrix with Playa cell

Tags: matrix, playa, pixelandtonic

in my expressionengine backend I use matrix to create an agenda for events. The fields are:
day, time, title, description, file and speaker (using playa field).

Filling this matrix field with e.g. 24 rows slows down the backend. Clicking in a normal input field to fill it out takes ages. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could add your EE, Matrix and Playa version numbers to your question.

Comment: How many Speaker entries are displaying in your Playa field? That's probably your problem. Each row is loading a resource-intensive Playa field.